# Atualizador de uma aplicação web asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

eu estava aqui pensando em uma estrutura para atualização automática dos meus sistemas web em clientes, daí pensei em utilizar o `ClickOnce` com algumas gambetas(adaptações técnicas).

Não deu certo, ele funciona apenas para aplicações `Windows-based`.

Pensei em algo como um `webservice` no `task scheduler` pra verificar se a ultima versão do sistema é a mesma do servidor de publicação, se não, faz o download dela e atualiza.

O que acham? Alguém tem uma ideia/alternativa para uma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Você já ouviu falar no framework [Quartz .NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)?

O Quartz .NET é um framework agendador open-source baseado no .NET. Parece ser uma ótima ferramenta. Nunca utilizei, mas segue alguns [tutoriais](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/index.html) de implementação.

Dê uma olhada, talvez isso te ajude!

Comment: De fato, parece ser uma boa ferramenta, mas no demais, digamos q poderia cumprir uma parte da solução que imaginei, o fato de substituir o task scheduler do windows.